# Reduxjs and Observables

Tags: redux, observable

What role do Observables play in implementing the redux library?

I have always wondered how actions communicate with reducers. When writing code, these functions don't call each other. (This is the most confusing part)

I can tell they are connected via types,  what is the role of these types in making the redux library work?

How does this pattern look diagrammatically? It will be helpful to wrap my head around this. Just the redux design no react or any other library or framework.

I am seeking to understand the underlying mechanisms of the library, not how to use it

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux has nothing to do with observables as such.

A basic Redux store implementation looks like this:

```js
function createStore(reducer, preloadedState) {
  let state = preloadedState
  const listeners = []

  function getState() {
    return state
  }

  function subscribe(listener) {
    listeners.push(listener)
    return function unsubscribe() {
      const index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
      listeners.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }

  function dispatch(action) {
    state = reducer(state, action)
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener())
  }

  dispatch({ type: '@@redux/INIT' })

  return { dispatch, subscribe, getState }
}
```

Calling `store.dispatch(action)` causes the store to run `state = reducer(state, action)`.  There really is only that *one* "root reducer" function.  But, we typically implement that root reducer by [splitting it up into many smaller "slice reducer" functions to do the work](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#splitting-reducers), which makes it more maintainable.

So, in the end it's "just" a series of normal function calls:

- `store.dispatch(action)`

  - `reducer(state, action)`

    - `postsReducer(state.posts, action)`

Having said all that, the Redux store *can* be treated as an observable itself, and other observables can listen for updates to the state.  But no observables are used in the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. This is a good explanation about how redux works. `Calling store.dispatch(action) causes the store to run state = reducer(state, action). ` I am seeking to understand the underlying mechanisms of the library

Comment: What triggers the reducers? How does that happen? I know it is because the state has changed, but what is the underlying process to achieve this?

Comment: I was going through the redux source code, they are using observables. Of course, we don't need to know anything about observables to make use of the library.

Comment: They don't "use" observables, they expose an `$$observable` property so that the store can be used as an observable. But that has nothing to do with the implementation of Redux itself. What Mark (by the way, he is one of the redux maintainers) wrote above is essentially a complete basic implementation of Redux (excluding store enhancers and middlewares).
It will even run. You do not need any more code to understand the basic Redux internals.

Comment: Got it thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, my explanation _is_ literally how Redux works :)  As I said, the only use of "observables" in the Redux library source code is the bit I mentioned about "a Redux store can be treated as an observable". A Redux store has a hidden `$$observable` property that lets actual observable libraries like RxJS treat a Redux store as an observable source, but that's it - it's an external adapter, not actual implementation of store behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Mark. I now get it. It is refreshing to start understanding the power of redux.